# XML File Error on MAC OSX (Minecraft)

Tags: xml, macos, minecraft

I'm trying to make a Tectonicus 2.25 map for my singleplayer world in minecraft 1.12.1. Therefore I need a XML config file, but when trying to make the map I get this error in Terminal (MAC OSX) (Please take a look at: https://github.com/tectonicus/tectonicus/wiki/Creating-a-Tectonicus-config-file:

```
Parsing config from /Users/ralphvandenheuvel/Downloads
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/Users/ralphvandenheuvel/Downloads/; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:205)
at tectonicus.configuration.XmlConfigurationParser.loadXml(Unknown Source)
at tectonicus.configuration.XmlConfigurationParser.parseConfiguration(Unknown Source)
at tectonicus.TectonicusApp.main(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't get root 
config node from /Users/ralphvandenheuvel/Downloads
at tectonicus.configuration.XmlConfigurationParser.parseConfiguration(Unknown Source)
at tectonicus.TectonicusApp.main(Unknown Source)"
```

My file is made with Texteditor (Standard MAC OSX)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tectonicus version="2">
    <config mode="cmd" outputDir="/Users/ralphvandenheuvel/Downloads"/>
    <map name="GLACIER" worldDir="/Users/ralphvandenheuvel/Library/Application Support/minecraft/saves/GLACIER/level">
        <layer name="Day" lighting="day"/>
    </map>
</tectonicus>
```

What is the problem? Also I do not know if my xml is 1.0??? For answering, I'm not the best in XML programming, so please, keep the answer simple :)

EDIT: I've tried to locate a BOM, but there is no sign of it (Hex Friend, Emacs; still no sign). I do not know if there could be something else making the code 'false'.

Comment: I am sorry, but this is a new xml file that I made days after the first one.

Comment: What? This is a different xml file!! This is very strange, you should not mark something when you do not know the full story from the writer....

Comment: It may be a different file, but it had the same error. If you feel that the duplicate is unwarranted, edit your question and explain why.